# pass parameters to dll?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm new to c++ and Access. I'm working with a project calls dll (compiled by c++) from Access.
I want to understand how are the parameters passed into the dll.

The input data for dll is prepared in Access, and we call the dll from Access.
We associate "RunFunction" with the dll we want to call.
The line in Access calls the dll:

```
Results = RunFunction(Data.age, Data.calendar, Data.timesheet, Data.extra)
```

The cpp code that complies the dll:

```
double __stdcall RunFunction(double * iData, double(*iCalendar)[100], double(*iTimesheet)[100])
```

First question, from the cpp code, I found the *iData(in c++) actually contains all info from Data (in Access).
Why it could happen? I thought only Data.age is passed into *iData, not the whole Data?

Second question, the the RunFunction from Access has four input parameters, while c++ only takes three, why it doesn't this cause any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider that inside Access the value of `Data.age` might be inside a buffer containing the entire record or some other structure. So when the address of that one value is passed to you in C++, you can explore neighboring addresses and see what’s in it.  Don’t do that!

Second, look at the way `__stdcall` works. It was designed in the early days of C when function arguments were not checked at all! You can pass fewer or more parameters on the caller side and not mess up the stack.  If you pass extra, no big deal. If you leave off some, then using the rightmost names in the function will give garbage values and *witing* to them can cause all sorts of problems including clobbering the return address.